# How to get `fcm_options.link` functioning in firebase web notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get my FCM web notifications to contain a clickable link to my site, using the firebase admin SDK (version 7.0.0) for node.js. As far as I can tell I'm following the documentation to a T, but I'm unable to get the link working. To clarify, my notifications are working fine otherwise, it's just the link that I haven't got to work.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) states:

> For notification messages sent from the app server, the FCM JavaScript API supports the fcm_options.link key. Typically this is set to a page in your web app

I've included `webpush.fcm_options.link` inside my notification message. I've made sure to include an explicit `notification` payload in my message, as the documentation states that `data` messages don't support `fcm_options.link`.

Here's the structure of my message currently:

```
{
    notification: {
        title: 'Title',
        body: 'Body',
    },
    data: {
       // my data here
    },
    webpush: {
        notification: {
            requireInteraction: true,
            icon: '/icons/notification.png'
        },
        fcm_options: {
            link: 'https://example.com/'
        }
    },
    // android: {},
    // apns: {},
    topic: 'sometopic'
};
```

Here's the function I'm using to send the message:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

const sendMessage = message => {
    admin
        .messaging()
        .send(message)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
};
```

The `link` property should be working according to the documentation: my url includes `https` and my notification is being sent from the app server, and includes an explicit notification payload. At the moment, clicking on the notification just makes it disappear, with nothing else happening.

Comment: Hmm...That does all look correct. I wanted to make sure you were using the new FCM API and it looks like you are. What version of Admin are you using? I'll try to find out more from the team in the meantime

Comment: @JenPerson using `7.1.1` as of a few days ago, and yes i'm using the v1 api. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could you also tell which version of the Firebase client SDK you are using?

Comment: @MertcanMermerkaya `5.8.5`

Comment: I tried your payload in both `5.8.5` and also the latest version. It works perfectly. Are you maybe creating your own notification instead of letting the SDK do it for you, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker) under "Setting notification options in the service worker"?

Comment: @MertcanMermerkaya yes, I think this might be where the issue is. could you show me what your service worker looks like?

Comment: Just two lines should be enough: `firebase.initializeApp(<your_app_config>); firebase.messaging();`. If you don't call `setBackgroundMessageHandler`, the SDK will create the notification itself, and `link` should work.

Comment: @MertcanMermerkaya the issue was a version of firebase that didn't support `fcm_options.link` in my `importScripts` functions in my sw. can't believe i didn't notice until now! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: I worked out what the issue was - my service worker was using the `importScripts` function, but I was using an out-of-date version of the firebase script that didn't support `fcm_options.link`. I changed it to my current version of firebase (`5.8.5`) and it works. All sorted!

Comment: Had the same issue, and turned out to be the same thing, thanks for the update.

Comment: @camargue92 Thanks. That did it for me. Guess we copied the code from the [firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground). You should mark this as accepted.

Comment: my current version is 7.6.2, already matched with the sw.js but fcm throwing error when sending
```Messaging payload contains an invalid "webpush" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification"```
any other clues?

Comment: I end up using [FCM Data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)
 and handle showing notification (and click event) from service worker [notificationclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient/focus)

Answer (score 8):

in notification try This

```
"notification":{
"title":"IssA",
"body":"Lafi",
"icon": "Icon URL",
"click_action": "Your URL here"
}
```

Comment: this is the current solution for javascript SDK 7.1.0

Comment: this is for Firebase FCM

Answer (score 1):

In the last version, using firebase admin in node js, this is the right configuration:

```
        var message = {
          notification: {
            title: "",
            body: ""                
          },
          webpush: {
            fcmOptions: {
              link: "https://yourlink.web.app"
            }
          }
        };
```